# How can I uninstall VMware-Player?

Tags: uninstall, vmware

How can I uninstall VMware-Player?
It is not listed in Ubuntu Software Centre or Synaptic Package Manager
I am using version 3.1.4

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Using installer VMware-Player-3.1.4-385536.i386.bundle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`gksudo vmware-installer -u vmware-player` will do the trick for you.