# How to uninstall VMware Player 4.0.3 on 12.04?

Tags: uninstall, vmware

I installed VMware Player 4.0.3 on Ubuntu 12.04. When I try to run an image, I get errors such as `"/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.` or `"~/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.`.

I tried patching it but I get `unable to install vmnet` message from the patch, thus I would like to uninstall the Player and re-install it.

The install file was a bash script downloaded from vmware, not a package, it doesn't appear in dpkg. SO, how do you uninstall VMware Player 4.0.3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the switch: `--uninstall-component=vmware-player`

That uninstalled it for me.

Comment: Thanks! That's the one! Full command is sudo ./installer --uninstall-component=vmware-player

Comment: What's the full command, and from where do you issue it?

Answer (score 3):

Since I noticed the answer is not contained in this thread,  I figured I would go ahead and add it for those looking for it:

Answers were close -- the command is the following:

```
sudo sh VMware-Player-4.0.3-703057.x86_64.bundle --uninstall-component=vmware-player
```

Though this is probably obvious, update the name to reflect the installation package name you're using.

Answer (score 1):

All you gotta do is goto usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.0 run script vmware-uninstall-downgrade. then run script vmware-installer and read it will give you directions and options :)

Answer (score 0):

Poking through the install script, it looks like running the installer again should give you the option to remove it.

However, in a similar question, someone has recommended:
`gksudo vmware-installer -u vmware-player`. (See [How can I uninstall VMware-Player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65633/how-can-i-uninstall-vmware-player))

Failing that, there should be an entry somewhere in /etc, possibly in /etc/bin/vm-something, /etc/locations (if it exists) or /etc/vmware-something.

This is all I can gather from the installer.

Comment: Both methods does not work. Running the script again only gets "The system is up to date. Nothing has been modified." Running the command prints "User vmware-player does not exist"